# Using font-awesome in python django application

Tags: python, django, font-awesome

I'm trying to load a local copy of font awesome icons in my python django app, to use the pro icons in my application.

My template base.html contains:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'appointments/css/all.css' %}" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}Hello, world!{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

as adapted from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

The directory structure of my app is:

```
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ tree
.
├── appointments
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── appointments
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── all.css
│   │       └── webfonts
│   │           ├── fa-brands-400.eot
│   │           ├── fa-brands-400.svg
│   │           ├── fa-brands-400.ttf
│   │           ├── fa-brands-400.woff
│   │           ├── fa-brands-400.woff2
│   │           ├── fa-regular-400.eot
│   │           ├── fa-regular-400.svg
│   │           ├── fa-regular-400.ttf
│   │           ├── fa-regular-400.woff
│   │           ├── fa-regular-400.woff2
│   │           ├── fa-solid-900.eot
│   │           ├── fa-solid-900.svg
│   │           ├── fa-solid-900.ttf
│   │           ├── fa-solid-900.woff
│   │           └── fa-solid-900.woff2
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── appointments
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── createappointment.html
│   │       ├── doctor.html
│   │       ├── doctors.html
│   │       ├── home.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── navbar.html
│   │       ├── patient.html
│   │       └── patients.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── using shell.txt
│   └── views.py
├── appointments.ipynb
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── myappointments
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
```

However these icons are not being served. It works if I use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: do you have all fonts file inside `webfonts` folder i.e `.ttf`, `.woff`, `.eot` etc

Comment: Yes I do. I didnt include them in the tree for brevity.

Comment: use single quote while using static tag i.e `href="{% static '/appointments/css/all.css/' %}"`

Comment: Tried that too.. Edited post to what I tried with single quotes

Comment: do you see any console logs in your browser inspect

Comment: Thank you. I found that it was referencing a wrong path. I edited my STATIC_URL to point to the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Django wasn't able to find the webfonts directory - when I ran `python manage.py runserver`, I could see `404` responses for the font-awesome files.

Inside your `all.css` file, right at the bottom, you should see a few `src: url(../webfonts/..)` attributes. Change these to `src: url("/static/webfonts/..)`. When you `runserver` you should see a `200` response instead of `404`, indicating that your files have been found.

If there are still errors, check the console. Right click on the icon (where it should be), click "inspect", click "console" (in Chrome; or whatever your browser's equivalent is)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem,
wanted to comment it to say  someone posted on pypi :
https://pypi.org/project/django-static-fontawesome/
a "clean" css with good "url" link,

without ron g i would have never figured why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but Google didn't show it to me in the results so I think it's important to add it here. Font awsome now has a Python package, which makes it very easy to use.
Install it with:

```
pip install fontawesomefree
```

more details are here:
https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/python-django